# How to see complete list of processes in top

Tags: linux, process, administration, top

When I do 'top', I learn that there are many processes running out of which many are in sleep state. I need to see complete snapshot of all processes at that point. the 'top' is able to show listing of processes, which fit in one screen.How do I get complete listing?

Among other things, I am interested in seeing list of all processes, which are in "sleeping" state. I don't think, I can get process state in output of "ps" command

Comment: See if you have [`htop`](http://htop.sourceforge.net/). Its process list is scrollable.

Answer (score 20):

`top -b` seems to be doing the trick.

Comment: Adding `-n1` option will gives one full page then exit.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not allow interactive operation.

Comment: Note: although the question was tagged linux, ```top -l1``` works in OS X/macOS to list all processes with states, although %CPU will be incorrect for a single sample with -l, as it is calculated using the delta between samples.

Comment: @GaryS.Weaver thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can get process states with coreutils `ps`

```
$ ps aux
```

will list all that, and more. Here's how you can decode them, from the man page:

> PROCESS STATE CODES
>
> Here are the different values that the s, stat and state output specifiers (header "STAT" or "S") will display to describe the state of a process:

```
   D    uninterruptible sleep (usually IO)
   R    running or runnable (on run queue)
   S    interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)
   T    stopped, either by a job control signal or because it is being traced.
   W    paging (not valid since the 2.6.xx kernel)
   X    dead (should never be seen)
   Z    defunct ("zombie") process, terminated but not reaped by its parent.
```

> For BSD formats and when the stat keyword is used, additional characters may be displayed:

```
   <    high-priority (not nice to other users)
   N    low-priority (nice to other users)
   L    has pages locked into memory (for real-time and custom IO)
   s    is a session leader
   l    is multi-threaded (using CLONE_THREAD, like NPTL pthreads do)
   +    is in the foreground process group.
```